# How to hide button in overflow?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

In a WPF app, I have a toolbar with several panels.  There is one panel with two buttons. Each button has text and an image. I want to add a third button, which is accessible only through the right panel arrow. I think this is called overflow?

Each button is created like this:

```
<Button x:Name="someButton" click"someButton_click">
  <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinitions Height="Auto"/>
      <RowDefinitions Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinitions Height="Auto"/>
      <RowDefinitions Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Image Source="myimage.png" Margin="0" Grid.Row="0" Height="32" Width="32"/>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Margin="0">
      <TextBlock Text="click me" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    </StackPanel>
   </Grid>
  </Button>
```

How do I add this third button so it is not visible in the toolbar but accessible through the right arrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using the basic toolbar control from WPF, then according to [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752063(v=vs.110).aspx), you can set a `ToolBar.OverflowMode` to `Always`:

```
<Button ToolBar.OverflowMode="Always">
  <Image Source="toolbargraphics\save.bmp" />
</Button>
```

and that should make it

> permanently placed in the overflow panel

as stated in the docs for [OverflowMode enum](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.overflowmode(v=vs.110).aspx)